# PHP DOM, method chaining

Tags: php, method-chaining

I have the following code-line, whereas the first notation does what it should (adding an XML-element and its content to the DOM), but not if I chain the methods.

```
/**
 * @var string $key
 * @var DOMNode $value
 */
$newElem = $dom->createElement($key);
$newElem->appendChild($value);
```

The following example will result in E_WARNING: DOMNode::appendChild(): Couldn't fetch DOMNode. (Costs me about an hour to find that bug/error.)

```
$newElem = $dom->createElement($key)->appendChild($value);
```

Can anyone explain why the same code in different notations leads to errors?

EDIT: I've [uploaded a test-case](http://pastebin.com/Kd0vA5Sz), which results in an E-WARNING-error, when running with PHP 5.3.5.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Can you show whats in `$key` and `$value`?

Comment: Same here, works as expected and now error is shown; which exact PHP version do you use?

Comment: Its executed in a loop, key is always a string, naming the new element (e.g. 'name'). Value is either `DOMCharacterData` or `DOMText`, depending on the key (e.g. `$dom->createTextNode('Test-Marker')`). I've tested the program several times without changing any other part then the one pasted above. I'm using PHP 5.3.5 on Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible, due to PHP's syntax, for there to be a difference here.

`$b = $a; $b->c();` is the same as `$a->c();`.

Something else is wrong with your code.

Comment: "It is impossible" - at least it should be :)

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
$newElem = ($dom->createElement($key))->appendChild($value);
```

remember that in this case $newElem is the added Node, not the parent element.

Comment: The additional parentheses shouldn't change the functionality.